# How to iterate over pandas dataframe column which is a list and then map to new values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below. I want to iterate through the "label" column values and replace to new values which is label_dict = {1:'production', 2:'to_be_discussed'}

```
    Name    label   score
0   prdn    [2, 1]  [0.886071, 0.78242475]
1   tbd     [1]     [0.9897076]
```

I tried below line of code, but looks like it doest work for listed column values.

```
df['label'].replace(label_dict, inplace=True)
```

How to iterate over the column and change to new values?

Answer (score 3):

Solution working with lists in column `label`:

```
#if not lists but strings create them
#import ast
#df['label'] = df['label'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Solution with removing values from original column if not exist in keys of dict:

```
label_dict = {1:'production', 2:'to_be_discussed'}
df['label'] = df['label'].apply(lambda x: [label_dict[y] for y in x if y in label_dict])
```

Solution with NOT removing values from original column if not exist in keys of dict:

```
label_dict = {1:'production', 2:'to_be_discussed'}
df['label'] = df['label'].apply(lambda x: [label_dict.get(y, y) for y in x])
```

Difference in changed sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'label':[[2,1,5], [1]]})

label_dict = {1:'production', 2:'to_be_discussed'}
df['label1'] = df['label'].apply(lambda x: [label_dict[y] for y in x if y in label_dict])

df['label2'] = df['label'].apply(lambda x: [label_dict.get(y, y) for y in x])

print (df)
       label                         label1                            label2
0  [2, 1, 5]  [to_be_discussed, production]  [to_be_discussed, production, 5]
1        [1]                   [production]                      [production]
```